# Partial database recovery on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, backup, database-restore

Thankfully this is a hypothetical, planning-ahead sort of a question. Can you restore part of a database using Heroku's backup addon, or otherwise? So, for instance, only restore records in all tables which have a client_id of 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that does not appear to be a feature included in the PG Backups addon provided by Heroku: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#restoring_from_a_backup

Comment: Ta for that - good to know I wasn't missing something obvious. Can you think of a genius alternative way?

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is solve a problem that tools like `acts_as_audited` solve. Might be worth a look.